# Форматировани фото на PHP

Tags: php, gd

И так, на сайте для похудения для прекрасного пола, создаю конструкцию, в которой пользователь может добавить фото ДО участия в проекте и ПОСЛЕ,

Сам процесс записи файла на сервер реализовать не проблема, трудность в том, что проси не проси, участницы фоткаются кто вериткально, кто горизонтально, кто 1:1, а учитывая современное кол-во соотношений сторон фото - задача стает не приятная)

Имея входящий файл-картинку, с произвольной ориентацией и размерами, я бы хотел все приводить к стандартному (в моем понимании() виду.

Работаю процедурно. Осознаю, что скорее всего ужно будет делать при помощи GD!

`$file = $_FILES['file'];`

Может подскажите ссылкой на видео или ресус, где можно получить ответ на вопрос

ЗЫ Не против даже привести файл вертикальной или горизонтальной ориентации к квадрату, если это упростит задачу)

Answer (score 0):

На данном [сайте](https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/manipulating-images-in-php-using-gd--cms-31701) довольно хорошо описаны многие действия с изображениями. От создания картинки, до фильтров на ней. Как вариант изображение можно либо отдалять (`imagescale()`), либо изменять размер изображения, либо просто обрезать изображение (`imagecrop()`). В качестве примера привожу код изменения размера изображений с данного сайта

```
$directory = 'Nature/';
$images = glob($directory."*.jpg");
 
foreach($images as $image) {
    $im_php = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
    $im_php = imagescale($im_php, 640);
    $new_height = imagesy($im_php);
    $new_name = str_replace('-1920x1080', '-640x'.$new_height, basename($image)); 
    imagejpeg($im_php, $directory.'Resized/'.$new_name);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! Уже играюсь с кодом, подскажите, что то знает о приведении размеров к соотношению 9/16 ?) Было бы максимально полезно)

Answer (score 0):

И так решение найдено, вот как сдлал:

ВАЖНО: в итоговом коде я еще провел ряд проверок, (на наличие фала, на тип и на вертикальнсть. Этого требовала конкретно моя задача, тут в примере я опускаю детали и оставляю все самое сочное)

Создаем новое изображение из загржаемого файла:

```
$im_php = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
```

У нового фото, если он не квадрат, есть большая и меньшая сторона, вычисляем их

```
$size_max = max(imagesx($im_php), imagesy($im_php));
$size_min = min(imagesx($im_php), imagesy($im_php));
```

Мне нужен файл в соотношении 16:9, 16 это будет высота, обоначим ее как height

```
$height = $size_max;
```

Ширину же получим разделив высоту на 16 и умножим на 9! Таким образом мы обозначим ширину под каждую высоту и в итоге получим правильное соотношение сторон

```
$width = ($height / 16) * 9;
```

Если загружаемое фото было 17/9 или 18/9, то программа подставит черный фон, только проблема, что тело фотки при этом будет прижато к левому краю. Нужно вычислить расттояние, на котором тело будет отодвинуто от левого края. Это что то типа padding-left (если говорить на CSS-овском). Дальше немного маги. От ширины изначальной картинки отнимаем то самое 9 из соотношений, и полученый результат делим на пополам, таким образом установив это значение по иксу, тело изображения окажется посредине черного поля!

```
$x = ($size_min - $width) / 2;
$im_php = imagecrop($im_php, ['x' => $x, 'y' => 0, 'width' => $width, 'height' => $height]);
```

Длее оставлюбез комментариев, все и так понятно)

```
$path = '../../img/users_bef_after/';
$new_name = $username.'_'.$field_id.'.jpg'; 
imagejpeg($im_php, $path.$new_name);
```

По результатам работы кода, если изначальное фото "ниже", то по бокам обрежутся тонкие полосочки, в результате чего получим файл в 16/9, если фото будет "выше", то по бокам к нему добаявятся черные полосочки)

Это более чем удовлетворяет мой запрос и решение то самое!) Всем спасибо) и спасибо @pashok за наводку)